# E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, amazon-ec2

While I try to install K8s in EC2 ubuntu but i am facing some issue like this
E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

i can not edit the file too

I am following instruction form this blog :
https://medium.com/@mehmetodabashi/installing-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-20-04-e49c43c63d0c

need  guidance how to get the  solution
what is the issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the reason you're getting the error is because if you copy-pasted the text directly, you've also copied the curly double-quotes `“` -- which is not the same as the standard double-quotes `"`

It's likely the author of that blog post may have copy-pasted it from somewhere else, where that double-quote was friendly-formatted (such as in MS Word)

To edit the `kubernetes.list`, you will need to use `sudo`

`sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list`

Answer (score 1):

This is the command I had passed

echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/sublimehq.gpg] https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list

I corrected the error by including double quotes rather than a single quotation mark that is, correcting the above to:

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/sublimehq.gpg] https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list